# How to check if you can move a tetris piece to left or right

Tags: java, collision, tetris

So I am making a Tetris game as a learning project in Java. The structure of the game is that I have a block class, which holds the coordinates of each block, and also I have a tetromino class, which holds an array of blocks and can change all of their X and Y. So this here is my check for vertical collision:

```
    private static boolean collisionCheck(ArrayList<Block> staticBlocks, ArrayList<Block> blocks) {
        if (staticBlocks != null && blocks != null) {
            Block curBlock = blocks.get(3);
            Block otherBlock = blocks.get(2);
            for (Block block : staticBlocks) {
                if ((curBlock.getY() == block.getY() - 20
                              && curBlock.getX() == block.getX())
                          || (otherBlock.getY() == block.getY() - 20
                              && otherBlock.getX() == block.getX())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

staticBlocks, holds all of the blocks which are already dropped, or left from previous tetrominoes, blocks holds the current moveable blocks, which are in the dropping tetromino

I am looking for an idea on how to check for horizontal collision(when moving to left or to right), when I tried doing it the same way horizontally, collision was ignored, the method never returned true

The reason for the -20 is because the height and width of each block is 20

Comment: Lots of unclear things here: Why `blocks.get(2)` and `blocks.get(3)`? Why are you checking for null-collections at the start of the method? Why is your method called `collisionCheck`? That's a confusing name. I would expect it to be a void, which throws an `Exception` if there is a collision.

Comment: it checks for collision between 2 tetris blocks, returns true so I know if they collide so I stop the movement, ignore the checking for null, blocks.get(2) and 3 are so I get the 2 lowest blocks of the the tetris piece and use them to check if they would collide with a static block.